# Table with query per row

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, ajax

I am looking for some tutorial which show me how to make good table using AJAX.
For example, I got table where I got users and also table where I got user records.

Users table

```
UserID | Name
=======|===========
000001 | Kristian
000002 | David
000003 | Tomas
000004 | Philip
000005 | John
```

Runs Table

```
UserID | RouteName | RunTime
============================
000001 | Route#001 | 45
000001 | Route#002 | 30
000001 | Route#003 | 20
000002 | Route#001 | 10
000002 | Route#002 | 5
000002 | Route#003 | 25
000003 | Route#001 | 25
000003 | Route#002 | 50
000004 | Route#002 | 100
000004 | Route#003 | 200
000003 | Route#001 | 300
```

And I want to create a table where you will be able to see Position per RouteName by RunTime for specific UserID.

Final Table for UserID 000001

```
RouteName | RunTime | Position
==============================
Route#001 |    45   |   3/4
Route#002 |    30   |   2/4
Route#003 |    20   |   1/3
```

To create a table like this in PHP require one query to SELECT every run per user and also 2 queries per Row to calculate position and count of Route times.

And I don't have just few Routes I got 500+ routes and if I run it in one WHILE it took match time, so I am looking for some Tutorial use AJAX and row pagination or help to create this.
Thanks.

Comment: I was trying to create it with https://datatables.net/ but I don't have skills for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, 
        rank() over(partition by routename order by runtime) rn,
        count(*) over(partition by routename) cnt
    from mytable t
) t
where userid = 1
```

This selects all rows of the table for the given `userid`, with two additional columns:

- `rn` is the rank of the user on each route; the fastest user gets rank `1`, and users with the same run time get the same rank
- `cnt` is the total number of users that appear on each route